# Adding public ipv6 addresses to a server

Tags: ipv6

I just ordered a VPS with an IPv6 subnet routed to it so I can test a software that is supposed to work on IPv6.

This is my first encounter with IPv6 and I'm curious to know how to add them into the `/etc/network/interfaces` file for example. I know how to add IPv4 but I'm having a difficult time here because the subnet that was allocated to me (`2a0e:f500:2::/48`), once converted, shows `1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176` usable addresses. I don't think I'm supposed to add all those addresses in my interfaces - maybe smaller subnets.

I have a bit of software written in Golang by me that generates addresses and here's what I got out from this subnet:

```
2a0e:f500:2::1
2a0e:f500:2::2
2a0e:f500:2::3
2a0e:f500:2::4
2a0e:f500:2::5
2a0e:f500:2::6
2a0e:f500:2::7
2a0e:f500:2::8
2a0e:f500:2::9
2a0e:f500:2::a
2a0e:f500:2::b
2a0e:f500:2::c
2a0e:f500:2::d
2a0e:f500:2::e
2a0e:f500:2::f
2a0e:f500:2::10
2a0e:f500:2::11
2a0e:f500:2::12
2a0e:f500:2::13
2a0e:f500:2::14
2a0e:f500:2::15
2a0e:f500:2::16
2a0e:f500:2::17
2a0e:f500:2::18
2a0e:f500:2::19
2a0e:f500:2::1a
2a0e:f500:2::1b
2a0e:f500:2::1c
2a0e:f500:2::1d
2a0e:f500:2::1e
2a0e:f500:2::1f
2a0e:f500:2::20
2a0e:f500:2::21
2a0e:f500:2::22
2a0e:f500:2::23
2a0e:f500:2::24
2a0e:f500:2::25
2a0e:f500:2::26
2a0e:f500:2::27
2a0e:f500:2::28
2a0e:f500:2::29
2a0e:f500:2::2a
2a0e:f500:2::2b
2a0e:f500:2::2c
2a0e:f500:2::2d
2a0e:f500:2::2e
2a0e:f500:2::2f
2a0e:f500:2::30
2a0e:f500:2::31
2a0e:f500:2::32
2a0e:f500:2::33
2a0e:f500:2::34
2a0e:f500:2::35
2a0e:f500:2::36
2a0e:f500:2::37
2a0e:f500:2::38
2a0e:f500:2::39
2a0e:f500:2::3a
2a0e:f500:2::3b
2a0e:f500:2::3c
2a0e:f500:2::3d
2a0e:f500:2::3e
2a0e:f500:2::3f
2a0e:f500:2::40
2a0e:f500:2::41
2a0e:f500:2::42
2a0e:f500:2::43
2a0e:f500:2::44
2a0e:f500:2::45
2a0e:f500:2::46
2a0e:f500:2::47
2a0e:f500:2::48
2a0e:f500:2::49
2a0e:f500:2::4a
2a0e:f500:2::4b
2a0e:f500:2::4c
2a0e:f500:2::4d
2a0e:f500:2::4e
2a0e:f500:2::4f
2a0e:f500:2::50
2a0e:f500:2::51
2a0e:f500:2::52
2a0e:f500:2::53
2a0e:f500:2::54
2a0e:f500:2::55
2a0e:f500:2::56
2a0e:f500:2::57
2a0e:f500:2::58
2a0e:f500:2::59
2a0e:f500:2::5a
2a0e:f500:2::5b
2a0e:f500:2::5c
2a0e:f500:2::5d
2a0e:f500:2::5e
2a0e:f500:2::5f
2a0e:f500:2::60
2a0e:f500:2::61
2a0e:f500:2::62
2a0e:f500:2::63
2a0e:f500:2::64
```

I see 100 entries here. Am I supposed to add these to my interfaces file or what?

Comment: You only need 1 of the addresses to be added for a single server. If you have additional services, you can use more of the addresses.

Comment: I purchased a server that has many addresses because my software uses them. (a proxy software Squid) so I need to add them all somehow so I can utilize them.

Comment: You can also add multiple addresses to the same interface, but the specifics depend on your server configuration and what you really want to do.

Comment: The idea behind a `/48` allocation is that you use IPv6 Prefix Delegation in your router to assign `/64` networks. You have 65,536 `/64` networks. Probably one of those networks is your transit network to the ISP, and the others are used in your LAN, and you assign addresses to your hosts on the networks that you use. Each host now gets a public address, restoring the IP end-to-end paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think I'm supposed to add all those addresses in my interfaces - maybe smaller subnets.

Absolutely. Forget about counting individual IP addresses, and get familiar with sparse utilization. One standard on-link /64 has an enormous number of addresses.

Instead, consider a /48 as 65,536 /64s. Divide these on digit boundaries to suit your need to subnet. Perhaps test environments can have `2a0e:f500:2:ab00::/56`.  And perhaps the test server in question is on LAN `2a0e:f500:2:ab69::/64`. (I made this up, come up with your own addressing plan.)

Use the remaining 64 bits to generate an interface identifier, the local half of an IP address. SLAAC does this automatically. Which could result in an IP like  `2a0e:f500:2:ab69:2154:bb69:398f:7b47` (your address will be different). Insert into DNS as a AAAA record.

Should an application need multiple IP addresses, add more to the interfaces as static IPs.

No, you don't need to use all the IP addresses, that is an unusual configuration. In this case, for a HTTP proxy like Squid, configure HTTP agents to use the name you put in DNS as their proxy.